# the commands ls and get of ftp are not working in vmware

Tags: ftp, ls, vmware-player, minix

Iam using vmware player version 3.1 to boot a minix 3 os image. After booting the minix os I want to get some files from a server using ftp. the ftp connection to the server works but when i use the commands "ls" or "get" nothing happens except it says "200 PORT command successful" and it hanges in there. The only thing i can do after typing ls+enter or get+enter is to exit the ftp by using ctrl+c.

If anyone knows a solution to this? please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `passive` command before doing anything else, perhaps your firewall is blocking the inbound data connection (by default, the FTP server opens a data link back to the client — one of the bigger issues with FTP in our new "you can't trust everyone and leave everything open" world). [More on passive mode here.](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

Comment: your are right.good article.thank you very much.

Comment: @mnish: Excellent! Glad that was it. :-)